# Is it possible to create more system reserved space?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, 32-bit, system-reserved-partition

I installed windows xp(32bit) on a laptop.
But it had not a drivers for audio and the ethernet.
I managed to install the audio driver. It installed on drive C(system reserved space) and it took all space so no more for others.
When I tried installing on F:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers it didn't work

Can someone give me advise?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using device manager and updating and "choose location" - this points to the .inf file for the driver and it should install. If disk space is an issue (old laptop with 80gb or less - you dont say) then to move disk partitions you need to use a 3rd party partition software like paragon or Easus... I have resized the recovery partition but it can be tricky to do so.
Failing that you could wipe the disk and start again - make the boot partition "C" and not the reserved space.
As you installed drivers for audio and network then they didnt look for the "C" drive as boot so could be installed outside of the default windows directory on C: so F: worked.
or go into management console and change drive letter C to Z (not F) and then change F to C so it is the expected boot partition drive letter - then try the driver install.

Comment: So I should rename drives so that drive that has windows has name "C"

Comment: @Ben - The name of a mounted on Windows doesn’t do anything except identify the volume.  Changing the drive letter of the Windows will not solve your problem